# Collapse div horizontally to given width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to collapse a div (container) horizontally to a width I can set, and so hiding its content. Collapsing should go to the left.

```
    <div id="container">
    <button type="button" id="myButton">click here</button>
    <p id="myText">
my text here
    </p>
</div>
```

[**JSFDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/6sjzL80c/1/)

Comment: And ??? have you tried something?

Comment: I was trying to adapt/simplify this to my needs but it only became a mess: http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8wKxY/2/

Comment: I now have this http://jsfiddle.net/8wKxY/944/ but I do not want the sidebar to completely disappear. How do I set a value to keep it a portion in screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/19/

The sidebar has `position: relative` (with default 0/0). When toggle is clicked, `left`is animated to -55%, which keeps part of the sidebar still visible. When it's clicked again (being at `left: -55%`) it animates back to the initial state (if/else conditions + two animations):

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  SIDEBAR
  <button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").on('click', function () {
        var x = $("#sidebar").css("left");
    if(x == '0px') {
        $("#sidebar").animate({
            left: '-55%'
        });
        } else {
        $("#sidebar").animate({
            left: '0'
        });
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! That's it!! Very grateful!

Comment: You are welcome! FYI: I edited the answer once more to have the final working result included and deleted my comments.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this URL will help you. Try this. https://www.sanwebe.com/2011/11/horizontal-expand-collapse-using-jquery